# Swift backend using vapor framework postgresql

Tags: ios, swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

Hello everyone can anybody help me In this problem , i have a task that is we create an ios chat app and the client want the backend using postgresql and vapor framework , can any body help me to figure out how to add vapor to an existing xcode project and how to connect every thing together?

Comment: Vapor should be on the backend, so it is different project. Calls from iOS app to Vapor will be via JSON REST API and websockets. Vapor have great community on Discord where you could ask for help there and also find me there.

Comment: Can you please give me or help me how to join discord please !

Comment: go to https://vapor.codes there are the link to discord chat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Vapor app will live in a separate Xcode project as it's a separate app. In terms of connecting everything together, it's just another API to the client, so you call it like you would any other